# Getting data from table triple join

Tags: sql, database

I have three tables: product, order and order_products.
Product has 2 columns:product_id(pk) and product_sku
Order has 3 columns: order_id(pk), order_datetime and order_status
Order_products has 5 columns: op_id(pk), product_id(fk), order_id(fk), product_quantity and product_price.

I am trying to write an sql query that returns data from all the three tables but I get an error: `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order as o on op.order_id = o.order_id) on p.product_id = op.product_id) LIMIT 0' at line 2`

My query is this one: `select o.order_id, o.order_datetime, op.product_price ,op.product_quantity , op.product_id, p.sku, o.order_status_id  from (product AS p INNER JOIN (order_products AS op INNER JOIN order as o on op.order_id = o.order_id) on p.product_id = op.product_id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select o.order_id, o.order_datetime, op.product_price ,
 op.product_quantity , op.product_id, p.sku, o.order_status_id 
from  product AS p 
 INNER JOIN  order_products AS op on p.product_id = op.product_id
 INNER JOIN order as o on op.order_id = o.order_id ;
```

Comment: 6 errors were found during analysis.

    Unrecognized keyword. (near "as" at position 228)
    Unexpected token. (near "o" at position 231)
    Unexpected token. (near "=" at position 248)
    Unexpected token. (near "o" at position 250)
    Unexpected token. (near "." at position 251)
    Unexpected token. (near "order_id" at position 252)        #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order as o on op.order_id = o.order_id' at line 5

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to format but I get the errors from above

Comment: Very interesting. Could you please try remove AS from product p INNER JOIN order_products   op on p.product_id = op.product_id INNER JOIN order   o on op.order_id = o.order_id

Comment: select o.order_id, o.order_datetime, op.product_price ,
 op.product_quantity , op.product_id, p.sku, o.order_status_id 
from  product p 
 INNER JOIN  order_products AS op on p.product_id = op.product_id
 INNER JOIN order as o on op.order_id = o.order_id ;

Comment: Like above? It returns the same error.

Comment: No-no. Please remove all AS   select o.order_id, o.order_datetime, op.product_price ,
 op.product_quantity , op.product_id, p.sku, o.order_status_id 
from  product   p 
 INNER JOIN  order_products   op on p.product_id = op.product_id
 INNER JOIN order  O on op.order_id = o.order_id

Comment: select o.order_id, o.order_datetime, op.product_price ,
 op.product_quantity , op.product_id, p.sku, o.order_status_id 
from  product p 
 inner JOIN  order_products op on p.product_id = op.product_id
 inner JOIN order o on op.order_id = o.order_id ;

Comment: You mean like this? It says: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order o on op.order_id = o.order_id LIMIT 0, 25' at line 5

Comment: I guess you need to provide the complete query you execute, because LIMIT 0, 25 looks suspicious

Comment: select `order`.order_id, `order`.order_datetime, `order_products`.product_price , `order_products`.product_quantity , `order_products`.product_id, `order_products`.order_status_id from `order_products` inner join `order` on `order_products`.order_id=`order`.order_id     --------   I use this query to get most of the columns I need, what do I have to add to get the product sku column from my third table?